# MySQL large join query with multiple values where values help

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query that selects most of the information I need:

```
SELECT cm.*, companies.company_name, companies.permalink,last_met.*,(cm.total_unique_visitors - last_met.last_UV)/last_met.last_UV * 100 as percent_change FROM calculated_metrics as cm
    LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.company_id = cm.company_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id,total_unique_visitors as last_UV FROM calculated_metrics WHERE MONTH(date) = '04' AND YEAR(date) = '2011' GROUP BY company_id) last_met ON cm.company_id = last_met.company_id                         
    WHERE MONTH(cm.date) = '05' AND YEAR(cm.date) = '2011'
    AND cm.total_unique_visitors >3000
    AND cm.total_unique_visitors<9999999
    ORDER BY percent_change DESC
```

I have now been asked to sort the data even more.  I need to sort the data by 2 tables(marketing_strategy and product_type).
These tables both contain a company_id and multiple records for each company
***Example***

**marketing_strategy** (table) 
company_id       marketing_strategy_option_id
605                          25
605                         9
604                         21
604                         9

**product_type** (table) 
company_id       product_type_option_id
605                          12
605                         13
604                         13
604                         3

What is the best way to sort using these 2 tables and the query above?
I will have a comma delimited string for the marketing_strategy options and the product_type options.
(Ex. marketing_strategy: 25,9  product_type: 13,3)
Would it be easier to run the query above loop through using PHP and then select only the companies that contain the specific marketing_strategy and product_type id's?

I am at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have answered my own question.  Reading through SO I found what I was looking for: 
[Multiple Where conditions on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column)
So far query is working as expected.

```
SELECT cm.*, companies.company_name, companies.permalink,last_met.*,company_type_options_id,company_marketing_options_id,(cm.total_unique_visitors - last_met.last_UV)/last_met.last_UV * 100 as percent_change FROM calculated_metrics as cm
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.company_id = cm.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id,total_unique_visitors as last_UV FROM calculated_metrics WHERE MONTH(date) = '4' AND YEAR(date) = '2011' GROUP BY company_id) last_met ON cm.company_id = last_met.company_id
LEFT JOIN company_marketing_strategy ON cm.company_id = company_marketing_strategy.company_id
LEFT JOIN company_type ON cm.company_id = company_type.company_id
WHERE MONTH(cm.date) = '05' AND YEAR(cm.date) = '2011'
AND company_marketing_options_id IN (25,21)
AND company_type_options_id IN (3)
AND cm.total_unique_visitors >3000
AND cm.total_unique_visitors<9999999999
GROUP BY cm.company_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT company_marketing_options_id) = 2
AND COUNT(DISTINCT company_type_options_id) = 1
ORDER BY percent_change DESC
```