# SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions on same column must exist simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen many posts but didn't get my answer i have a table with structure

```
 subject_level_id  | tutor_id  | level_id_fk  | subject_id_fk |
  118              | 99        | 4            | 1             |
  119              | 99        | 3            | 2             |
  120              | 99        | 3            | 3             |
  121              |100        | 3            | 1             | 
  122              |100        | 4            | 2             |
```

I want to extract tutor id's of tutors which teach 1, 2 or more subjects of a particular level( number of subjects depend upon user selection of subjects there can be  but level will be unique for aparticular query)

I have worked out a query with help from other posts but it is very slow and gets worse if number of subjects are more than two because I have 10,000 records of tutors my query is:

```
select distinct
   a.tutor_id
from
   tutor_preferred_level_subject as a
inner join
   tutor_preferred_level_subject as b
   on a.level_id_fk = b.level_id_fk
where
   a.subject_id_fk = 1 and
   b.subject_id_fk = 10 and
   a.level_id_fk = 3
```

Suggestion: [SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column)

The difference in this question and mine is that I want the tutors who teach exactly both the subjects.

**update**: yes main concern is performance, this query is working fine for two subjects but for more than two subjects mysql server keeps on processing forever. The index is `subject_level_id` and there are almost 13000 records in it and the below query returns around 6500 results.

as Jakub Sacha demanded these are the results of

```
EXPLAIN select distinct
   a.tutor_id
from
   tutor_preferred_level_subject as a
inner join
   tutor_preferred_level_subject as b
   on a.level_id_fk = b.level_id_fk
where
   a.subject_id_fk = 1 and
   b.subject_id_fk = 10 and
   a.level_id_fk = 3



id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref|
1   SIMPLE          a   ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL            NULL 
1   SIMPLE          b   ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL           NULL 

rows    Extra 
12733   Using where; Using temporary
12733   Using where; Distinct
```

Comment: Add output data for above table

Comment: Is your concern over the performance of this query? I don't see anything wrong with it syntax-wise... Does the table have any indexes and how many records are in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not seem to be doing what you describe. The join should be on `tutor_id` and not on `level_id_fk`.

You need the `DISTINCT` only if the `(level_id_fk, subject_id_fk, tutor_id)` combination is not unique:

```sql
SELECT                              
    -- DISTINCT
   a.tutor_id
FROM
   tutor_preferred_level_subject AS a
INNER JOIN
   tutor_preferred_level_subject AS b
       ON a.tutor_id = b.tutor_id
WHERE
   a.subject_id_fk = 1 AND
   a.level_id_fk = 3 AND
   b.subject_id_fk = 10 AND
   b.level_id_fk = 3 ;
```

Additionally, you should add a (unique) index on `(level_id_fk, subject_id_fk, tutor_id)` for efficiency:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tutor_preferred_level_subject
  ADD INDEX level_subject_tutor_IDX
    (level_id_fk, subject_id_fk, tutor_id) ;
```

Comment: thank u so much u made my day!! sorry for late response.god bless u.

Answer (score 1):

This will select all tutor_id that have exactly two distinct subjects that matches (1, 10):

```
SELECT
  Distinct tutor_id
FROM
  tutor_preferred_level_subject 
WHERE
  level_id_fk = 3
GROUP BY tutor_id, level_id_fk
HAVING
  Count(Distinct subject_id_fk) = 2 AND
  Sum(subject_id_fk NOT IN (1, 10)) = 0
```

Comment: this query will also give results that have subject_id 1 and any othe subject_id for example 1 and 4 or 6 and 10

Comment: @irohit786 edited, this will find only results that have exactly 1, 10

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that you need to inner join the table to itself, that is what will be causing the slowness as you get more and more rows.

You say you need "tutors which teach 1, 2 or more subjects of a particular level" which basically just means you need tutors that teach that particular level. So try grouping and using the HAVING clause (this will require that your data is clean of course)

```
SELECT a.tutor_id
FROM tutor_preferred_level_subject AS a
WHERE a.subject_id_fk IN (1,10)
  AND a.level_id_fk = 3
GROUP BY a.tutor_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: yes i need the tutor_id only but only those tutors must teach the selected subjects the above query will give which teach any of the subjects of level 3 i want the tutors which must teach the subjects with subject id 1 and 10 (both of these subjects)

Comment: This query does what you ask, that is why the `IN (1,10)` is there. Assuming you have no duplicate subject IDs it should work. Did you try to execute it?

Comment: yes i have duplicate subject ids only the `subject_level_id` is unque nothing else, yes i did execute it.sorry it doesnot give what i require