# How would I add more columns to the WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, sql, where-clause

I don't know what is the correct syntax for adding more columns to the `WHERE` clause of my `SELECT` statement.
(department is one of the fields I want to add and one other one.)

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            query = "select * from table_1 where Department = '" + DDl_Dep.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            Gview.DataSource = ds;
            Gview.DataBind();
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your current query pulls all fields back. You are only filtering on `Department`. If you want to add another condition to the WHERE clause, use `AND` or `OR` and the other condition. If you want to access columns other than `Department`, do it - your query already selects them all. If none of that makes immediate sense - stop writing code, and go to the bookstore and get a book on SQL.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column

Answer (score 1):

You are already selecting all your fields.

```
SELECT * FROM Department
```

means nothing else than: SELECT all fields from Department table
Or do you want to reduce the rows in the output?
Then you have to increase the WHERE clause with AND, ORs, etc.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, ... FROM Department WHERE Field1 = 'something' AND Field2 = 'something'
```

Comment: the two fields is two drop down list, every drop down return a different  value from DB. what i need is when i select one value or two from one drop down or from the two of them i except to see all the records from DB Related.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
select * from table_1 where Department ="HR" and SomeOtherColumn=""
```

Answer (score 0):

for example if this your Table: 
**[id][bla1][bla2][department][somefield]**

"select * from table_1 where Department = '" + DDl_Dep.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND somefield ='"+ someSelected!+"'";

Comment: Please don't post answers with SQL injection.

Comment: for some reason it's don't work, i try this select:                                           query = "select * from table_1 where Department = '" + DDl_Dep.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND role = '" + DDL_Role.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

Comment: I Found a solution: query = "select * from table_1 where (Department like '%' + @ search1 + '%') and more...";

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to add another column to a `WHERE` clause is to append it with the word `and` or `AND`.

I would format your query value as such:

```
query = "select * "
      + "from table_1 "
      + "where Department = '" + DDl_Dep.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"
      + "and ColumnNameHere = 'value'";
```

Comment: Please don't post answers with SQL injection.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Please post answer without SQL injection.