# Spring query where in () is not working

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to query faculties that have 3 subjects mysql statement is as the following

```
select * from faculty_subject where subject_id  in(1 and 3 and 2);
```

where 1, 2, 3 are subject ids. I only want courses that have all these subjects so that reason I am using and. But I do not why my spring query is not working. I tried different ways but it's returning faculties with the first subject id in this case 1. Here is my spring query

```
@Query(value = "select * from faculty_subject where subject_id in(?#{[0]} and ?#{[1]} and ?#{[1]})", nativeQuery =  true)
    List<FacultySubject> getFacultyBySubjects(long subjectTop, long subjectMid, long subjectBottom);
```

another one that did not work

```
 @Query(value = "select * from faculty_subject where subject_id in(?1 and ?2 and ?3)", nativeQuery =  true)
    List<FacultySubject> getFacultyBySubjects(long subjectTop, long subjectMid, long subjectBottom);
```

another query

```
@Query(value = "select * from faculty_subject where subject_id in(:#{#subjectTop} and :#{#subjectMid} and :#{#subjectBottom})", nativeQuery =  true)
List<FacultySubject> getFacultyBySubjects(@Param("subjectTop") long subjectTop,
                                          @Param("subjectMid") long subjectMid,
                                          @Param("subjectBottom") long subjectBottom);
```

Entity

```
@Entity
public class FacultySubject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private long facultyId;

    private int subjectId;

    public FacultySubject(long facultyId, int subjectId) {
        this.facultyId = facultyId;
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
    }

    public FacultySubject() {
    }
... getters and setters
```

[image: Here is my table]

Comment: Ok lets start with: 1 post your entities, 2 post your tables.

Comment: i just noticed he's doing native query

Comment: Where clause doesn't accept 'and' clauses in between I guess.

Comment: As @VinodChandak pointed it out, you should seperate your values with comma not `and`

Comment: then why it's working when I write in mysql

Comment: I do not want that result if I seperate with comma it will return faculties that have even 1 given subject, I want only faculties that have 3 subjects

Comment: I can't tell why it is working or maybe it is not working the way you want. Check this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: That's not possible, what you are asking is that a column having three different values for a row if I'm getting it right. In a single row, a column can have only one value.

Comment: Ok, once again  I am pointing this out if I write this on command line it is working 

select * from faculty_subject where subject_id  in(1 and 3 and 2);

Comment: I'm not still sure if it works and if it does, how. But I think this question has something similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column

Comment: MySQL IN syntax is here http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php   and no there is no AND as you have been advised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query(value = "select * from faculty_subject where subject_id in(?1 , ?2 , ?3) group by faculty_id having count(*)==3", nativeQuery =  true)
List<FacultySubject> getFacultyBySubjects(long subjectTop, long subjectMid, long subjectBottom);
```