# Multiple check in same column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below:

[image]

Here, I wanna run a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT model_id 
FROM model_attributes 
WHERE ((attributes_id=2 and attributes_value='32mb')) AND ((attributes_id=4 AND attributes_value='5.00 inch') OR (attributes_id=4 and attributes_value='6.00 inch')) AND ((attributes_id=5 and attributes_value='here') OR (attributes_id=5 and attributes_value='asfdsdf'))
```

which returns model_ids `8, 9`. But it seems like I can't put multiple conditions in the same fields.

I also tried solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column) post still nothing ! How can I get this result ? The way I used the `AND` clause is incorrect but resembles what logic I wanna implement in the query.

Comment: Your pseudo sql query is not logically right. Please provide your logic or expectation in details.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for rows where attributes_id is 2 and 4 and 5, that will never be true.

Try this:

```
WHERE (attributes_id=2 AND attributes_value='32mb') OR 
(attributes_id=4 AND attributes_value in ('5.00 inch', '6.00 inch') OR 
(attributes_id=5 AND attributes_valuein ('here', 'asfdsdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT model_id 
FROM model_attributes 
WHERE ((attributes_id=2 and attributes_value='32mb')) or ((attributes_id=4 AND attributes_value='5.00 inch') OR (attributes_id=4 and attributes_value='6.00 inch')) or ((attributes_id=5 and attributes_value='here') OR (attributes_id=5 and attributes_value='asfdsdf'))
```

make `and` to `or`like above i think `and` was logically wrong