# Selecting with Multiple OR and AND on same column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I looked over this at many sources but can't really get the solution, It's just that i want to select rows from a table on applying various AND and OR.

I have one table

```
ID    product_list_id    tag       tag_type    prod_categ
---   ---------------    ---       --------    ----------
66    19                 maroon    color       5
67    19                 printed   design      5
68    19                 cotton    fabric      5
69    20                 blue      color       5
70    20                 printed   design      5
```

etc...

I need here to get those product_list_id which are both maroon or blue, and printed (there could be multiple combinations of AND and OR)

basic query which i thought would work

```
select DISTINCT product_list_id 
FROM product_tags 
WHERE (tag = 'blue' OR tag = 'maroon') 
AND tag = 'printed'
```

but it returns nothing.

**Expected Output**

```
product_list_id
19
20
```

since, the product_list_id 19 and 20 is both printed and is either maroon or blue

P.S. I came through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column), but i need to include even some OR conditions in my result?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What is your expected output here?  And also please include the logic behind that output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Please see the updated question with the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach is to just aggregate by `product_list_id` and then assert the requirements:

```
SELECT product_list_id
FROM product_tags
GROUP BY product_list_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN tag = 'printed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN tag IN ('maroon', 'blue') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

We could also approach this using a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.product_list_id
FROM product_tags t1
INNER JOIN product_tags t2
    ON t1.product_list_id = t2.product_list_id AND
       t1.tag = 'printed' AND
       t2.tag IN ('maroon', 'blue');
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . The second query does an `OR` not and `AND` between the conditions.  Something that is just "maroon" will be in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is the intended logic, if I read the question correctly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . If that is the case, then your first query is wrong and the overall answer is overly complicated (a simple `in` would suffice).