# Select users with the same cities

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an user(id, name), city(id, name) and a join table users_cities(user_id, city_id) for a many to many relationship, like:

**cities**

```
 id | name 
----|------ 
  1 | NY   
  2 | LA   
  3 | CH   
  4 | HU
```

**users**

```
 id | name 
----|------ 
  1 | James   
  2 | Michael  
  3 | Robert   
  4 | Maria
```

**users_cities**

```
 user_id | city_id 
---------|--------- 
       1 |       1 
       1 |       3 
       2 |       3 
       3 |       1 
       3 |       4 
       4 |       1 
       4 |       3
```

There is a policy for the index of users where the current user can only see the list of users that doesn't have a city he doesn't have. Also:

*An user with some cities can see a user with no cities. And an user with no cities can see a user with no cities.*

**For a given user id, how can I select all users that have the same cities or a subset of it?**

For example when user James (with cities 1 and 3) is logged in, I expect him to see:

```
 id | name 
----|------ 
  1 | James   
  2 | Michael 
  4 | Maria
```

Discarding user Robert because Robert has city 4 and James doesn't. Or equivalently, Robert's cities (1,4) are not a subset of James's (1,3)

---

***EDIT***:
This sql shows the correct output for the example data and user James:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM   users 
       INNER JOIN users_cities 
               ON users_cities.user_id = users.id 
       INNER JOIN cities 
               ON cities.id = users_cities.city_id 
GROUP  BY users.id 
HAVING Group_concat(cities.id) IN ('1,3', '3,1', '1', '3')
```

[See this DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7LDh1nEbF5ms3SM4v18m3K/1)

And shows the correct ouput:

```
 id | name 
----|------ 
  1 | James   
  2 | Michael
  4 | Maria
```

But I don't know how to generate all the combinations of 1,3 ('1,3', '3,1', '1', '3') to use in the having clause for a given user id

---

This question it's very different than [SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column) because the condition for filtering users it is not in the same column or table, it is in the many-to-many relation.

Comment: Would a user with some cities see a user with no cities? Would a user with no cities see a user with no cities?

Comment: @Strawberry Regarding your questions, I say yes to both. Why did you mark the question as duplicate?

Comment: I didn't, but SO likes to generalise

Answer (score 0):

I would do :

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM   users 
       INNER JOIN users_cities ON users_cities.user_id = users.id 
WHERE  users_cities.id in (select id from users_cities.user_id = <JamesId>)
       and users.id <> <JamesId>;
```

Here the tricks to do this :

```
select id, name
from (
SELECT users.*, users_cities.city_id, ifnull(james_cities.city_id, 'NULL') james_city_id
FROM users
INNER JOIN users_cities ON users_cities.user_id = users.id
left join users_cities james_cities on james_cities.city_id = users_cities.city_id and james_cities.user_id = 1
union
select users.*, 'NULL', 'NULL'
from users where id not in (select user_id from users_cities)
) a 
group by id, name
having group_concat(city_id) = group_concat(james_city_id)
```

Comment: I think you meant:
`SELECT users.* FROM   users 
       INNER JOIN users_cities ON users_cities.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users_cities.city_id IN (select city_id from users_cities where users_cities.user_id = 1)`
But this doesn't meet the requirements, users are duplicated and id shouldn't show user Robert.