# How to make a query with AND operator between rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table, witch is the relationship pivot table, between posts and tags:

[post_tags table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l1JM.png)

I need to get the posts that strict contain a 'X' given tag(s).

For example:

- If I need posts with exclusively tags 1 and 2, it should returns post_id 1 and 4.
- If I need post with tag 2, it should only returns post_id 3.
- If I need post with tag 23, it should't returns nothing.

I've tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM `post_tags` WHERE tag_id = 1 OR tag_id = 2;
```

but obviously it returns all post_id with these tags_id

And with:

```
SELECT * FROM `post_tags` WHERE tag_id = 1 AND tag_id = 2;
```

It doest's return anything, because it's trying to comparate between columns.

Any solution?

Comment: You can check out this question, it is the same problem and already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4047484/6691087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `group by post_id` and check the conditions in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM post_tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING 
  SUM(tag_id NOT IN (1, 2)) = 0
  AND
  COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2
```

This will return only posts with tags 1 and 2 and no other tag.
For posts with only tag 2:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM post_tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING 
  SUM(tag_id <> 2) = 0
  AND
  COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 1
```

If each `post_id, tag_id` pair is **unique**, then you can do this:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM post_tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(tag_id IN (1, 2)) = COUNT(tag_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM post_tags pt
WHERE (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM post_tags
        WHERE pt.post_id = post_id
            AND post_tag IN (1, 2)

        ) = 2
```

Or you could use an in list (using similar logic):

```
SELECT *
FROM post_tags pt
WHERE post_id IN (
        SELECT post_id
        FROM post_tags
        WHERE post_tag IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY post_id
        HAVING count(*) = 2
        )
```