# How to write the following SQL query to find content with the desired tags?

Tags: sql

```
contents table
|id|content|
|1|content1|
|2|content2|
|3|content3|
```

```
tags table
|id|tag|
|1|tag1|
|2|tag2|
|3|tag3|
```

```
content_tags table
|content_id|tag_id|
|1|1|
|1|2|
|1|3|
|2|1|
|3|1|
```

Now I want to find content which has both tag2 and tag3. How do I write this SQL query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation is a simple method:

```
select ct.content_id
from content_tags ct join
     tags t
     on ct.tag_id = t.id
where t.tag in ('tag1', 'tag2')
group by ct.content_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
  select content_id
  from content_tags  join tags on tag_id=id
  where tags in ('tag1','tag2')
  group by content_id
  having count(distinct tags)=2
```