# Shorthand for AND when SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions on same column

Tags: sql-server, select, where-clause, shorthand

I have the table `PETS` with columns `Index`, `Owner` and `Animal` with following rows:

```
Index, Owner, Animal
--------------------
1, Anne, cat
2, Anne, dog
3, Anne, rabbit
4, Bill, dog
5, Bill, dog
6, Bill, rabbit
7, John, cat
8, John, dog
9, Johh, parrot
10, Susy, rabbit
11, Susy, parrot
12, Susy, parrot
```

I need two outputs: Get all Owners which own

1. a cat OR a dog
2. a cat AND a dog

The first output I get with `IN` as shorthand operator for `OR`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Owner FROM PETS WHERE Animal IN ('cat','dog')
```

Is there an equivalent shorthand operator for `AND`? The solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column) with `HAVING COUNT` does not quite work as it returns `'Bill'` as there is `'dog'` twice, however there is no `'cat'`.

Comment: You could pivot this data on owner column and then write a sane `WHERE` statement, perhaps?

Comment: 2 is just a special case of 1 unless there is more to your logic than what you suggest.

Comment: Did you scroll down to the second answer in the question you linked to that pointed out it should be using `COUNT(DISTINCT Animal)` rather than `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever - please add your comment as answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a shorthand, no, but personally I would use a `HAVING` with conditional aggregation for the owning both logic:

```sql
SELECT Owner
FROM dbo.Pets
GROUP BY Owner
HAVING COUNT(CASE Animal WHEN 'dog' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE Animal WHEN 'cat' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

And, obviously, you can easily change the above for your original requirement by changing the `AND` to an `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution with HAVING COUNT does not quite work as it returns
> 'Bill' as there is 'dog' twice, however there is no 'cat'.

IN ('cat','dog') selects all owners which have a cat or a dog (consequently, owners which have a cat AND a dog).
From the above cat_and/or_dog_owners, the count must be on DISTINCT animals: if a cat_and/or_dog_owner has 2 distinct animals then the owner has both a cat and a dog:

```
declare @t table (Id smallint, Owner varchar(10), Animal varchar(10))
insert into @t
values
--------------------
(1, 'Anne', 'cat'),
(2, 'Anne', 'dog'),
(3, 'Anne', 'rabbit'),
(4, 'Bill', 'dog'),
(5, 'Bill', 'dog'),
(6, 'Bill', 'rabbit'),
(7, 'John', 'cat'),
(8, 'John', 'dog'),
(9, 'Johh', 'parrot'),
(10, 'Susy', 'rabbit'),
(11, 'Susy', 'parrot'),
(12, 'Susy', 'parrot'),
(13, 'Susy', 'cat');--n

select owner , concat(min(animal), case when count(distinct animal) = 2 then ' & ' end, nullif(max(animal), min(animal))) as cat_dog_pet
from @t
WHERE Animal IN ('cat','dog')
group by owner;
```