# Multiple conditions over 2 columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am given a database with 3 different tables as such, and no sample data:
[image]

Basically, I'm trying to find a query for the number of users, for whom the last activity was done with `device_name = “phone”`, but who also have at least one additional activity with another device by combining data from the 3 tables.

The issue is that I can't include both those conditions in the same where clause because I'm they should be on different rows, i.e. different activites.

What I have so far is:

```
With CTE as (
    select * 
    from users u 
    join activities a on u.user_id=a.activity_user_id 
    join devices d on a.activity_device_ID=d.device_ID
) 
Select count(a.activity_user_id) 
from CTE 
where (a.activity_is_last='Yes' and d.device_name='phone')
```

I almost want to include some sort of when clause, so that WHEN the activity is last I want to check if the device is a phone, but when it's not I want to check if it's not phone. I also want to validate that there are at least 2 rows, is_last and not is_last. How is it possible?

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Please, add the one back that your are actually using.

Comment: That's not a "data warehouse" schema. That's just 3 tables with foreign key constraints

Comment: You would probably need an exists subquery or a join back to the same table or a subquery with conditional aggregation, but it is hard to tell due to lack of sample data and not knowing what database product you use. For mysql you could use the answers to the followin question as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column

Comment: First of all, try to limit posting photos to only when you can't describe it in textual form. In this case, you can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` on each of the tables you have and post the results [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68096832/edit). Second thing is, without any sample data that correspond to the situation you're having, it's hard to imagine what kind of issue you're having. Last but not least, **visualize** your expected output in your question.

Comment: Also dont use Non-Ascii quotes like you have in this question

Comment: Do *any* RDBMS permit those "smart quotes" for delimit identifying? (I hope not...)

Comment: @Shadow sorry I'm new to posting on stackoverflow, I'll be more aware of that.

Comment: @Shadow There is no sample data in fact, and I'll be using MySQL or T-SQL and will specify that in an edit of my post.

Comment: @FaNo_FN I realise it's not very clear via the info I've given, but this is in fact a case study question for an interview of a colleague of mine and they haven't supplied any sample data. In fact they mention that "any possible data set should be considered and not only a certain data sample, which is why we
strongly recommend not to create a sample database for testing. In case of huge databases, specialcases are quickly overlooked when testing queries only on samples. "

Comment: @RiggsFolly could you please clarify what non-ascii quotes are? I'm new here

Comment: @Salah people ask for data because they don't understand what you ask. To do what you want you need self-joins for starters, not CTEs. Have you tried that query with any database? You'll find syntax errors due to the use of `"` and `\`` instead of `'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't actually, thanks for pointing it out. Could you tell me more about the self-join in this case?

Comment: @Salah tsql is the language of ms sql server, which has different syntax to mysql. You really need to decide which one you are asking the question about. The non-ascii quotes are around phone and Yes.

Comment: non-ascii quotes are `“` and `’` use simple `"` and `'` Normally they get created when using a word processor to edit code rather than a simple text editor

Comment: Well then, you can just create fake data. Here, [try this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a67c60672aee0d0908e4094b251f076c)

Comment: Please share some sample data and desired output.

Comment: There is a [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN) in SQL Server, but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set." How did you manage to get `activity_is_last` into the `activities` table and why compare it to `'Yes'`?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used two `row_number()` window function to rank the output of inner query. RNK1 will represent the rank when `a.activity_is_last='Yes' and d.device_name='phone'` and RNK2 will represent the rank when `a.activity_is_last='No' and d.device_name<>'phone'`. Then in outer query I have selected first row from both the ranked and checked whether there are two rows or not with `having` clause and `group by`.

```
With CTE as (
    select * ,
    (case when (a.activity_is_last='Yes' and d.device_name='phone') then 
         row_number()over(partition by case when (a.activity_is_last='Yes' and d.device_name='phone') then activity_user_id end order by activity_timestamp desc) end) rnk1,
    (case when (a.activity_is_last='No' and d.device_name<>'phone') then 
         row_number()over(partition by case when (a.activity_is_last='No' and d.device_name<>'phone')  then activity_user_id end order by activity_timestamp desc) end) rnk2
    from users u 
    join activities a on u.user_id=a.activity_user_id 
    join devices d on a.activity_device_ID=d.device_ID
) 
Select activity_user_id
from CTE 
where rnk1=1 or rnk2=1
group by activity_user_id
having count(*)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you have some sample data. But I think this will work for you:

```
select * 
     ,case when d.device_name='phone' then 0 else 1 end as HasOtherdevice
into #tmp1
    from users u 
    join activities a on u.user_id=a.activity_user_id 
    join devices d on a.activity_device_ID=d.device_ID


Select a.activity_user_id,sum(HasOtherdevice)as cnt
into #tmp2
from #tmp1
group by a.activity_user_id

select count(a.activity_user_id) 
from #tmp1
where (a.activity_is_last='Yes' and d.device_name='phone') 
     and a.activity_user_id in (select a.activity_user_id
                                from #tmp2
                                where cnt=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can just do two conditional counts in a `HAVING` clause**

```sql
select u.user_id
from users u 
join activities a on u.user_id = a.activity_user_id 
join devices d on a.activity_device_ID = d.device_ID
group by u.user_id
having count(case when a.activity_is_last = 'Yes' and d.device_name = 'phone') > 0
   and count(case when a.activity_is_last = 'No' and d.device_name <> 'phone') > 0
```

---

Strictly speaking, **you should not store `activity_is_last`** in the database anyway, as it is defined just by being the latest row ordered by date. (And in any case it should be a `bit` column.)

So if you didn't have that column, **you would use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the top row**:

```sql
select u.user_id
from users u 
join (
    select *,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by a.activity_user_id order by a.activity_timestamp desc)
    from activities a
) a on u.user_id = a.activity_user_id 
join devices d on a.activity_device_ID = d.device_ID
group by u.user_id
having count(case when a.rn = 1 and d.device_name = 'phone') > 0
   and count(case when a.rn > 1 and d.device_name <> 'phone') > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way is to count in the subquery.

> Basically, I'm trying to find a query for the number of users, for whom the last activity was done with device_name = “phone”, but who also have at least one additional activity with another device by combining data from the 3 tables.

If I assume that `activity_is_last` is true on only one row, then:

```
with CTE as (
      select *,
             min(device_name) over (partition by user_id) as min_device_name,
             max(device_name) over (partition by user_id) as max_device_name
      from users u join
           activities a
           on u.user_id = a.activity_user_id join
           devices d
           on a.activity_device_ID = d.device_ID
     ) 
Select count(*) 
from cte
where activity_is_last = 'Yes' and device_name = 'phone' and
      min_device_name <> max_device_name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way seems to be to locate the base row(s) using WHERE activity_is_last='Yes' and d.device_name='phone'.  If activity_is_last='Yes' occurs once per user then the query returns unique user_id's.  Then use EXISTS to only count users with activity where at least 1 device_name is other than 'phone'.  Something like this

```
select count(a.activity_user_id) as num_of_users
from activities a
     join devices d on a.activity_device_ID=d.device_ID
where a.activity_is_last='Yes'
      and d.device_name='phone'
      and exists (select 1
                  from activities aa
                       join devices dd on aa.activity_device_ID=dd.device_ID
                  where a.activity_user_id=aa.activity_user_id
                        and dd.device_name<>'phone');
```