# SQL Output where there are multiple criteria. Subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

Here I have a table that has many rows and I ultimately want a final result where the rows are output based off of matching criteria. I would like to extract the Rows / or Col1 where Code includes values '1' and '3' together. I was looking to also add DISTINCT but not sure if needed because the initial table has many duplicate rows.

| Col1 | Col2 | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 132 | 1 |
| A | 132 | 3 |
| B | 141 | 3 |
| C | 149 | 2 |
| D | 100 | 7 |

The table would look like the table below:

| Col1 | Col2 | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 132 | 1 |
| A | 132 | 3 |

Edit. I've tried code similar to this from another posting. I modified it to cater to what I was looking for but was getting an error when using having and found the results were missing some rows I was expecting. [SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column)

SELECT T1.contact_id
FROM your_table T1
JOIN your_table T2 ON T1.contact_id = T2.contact_id AND T2.flag = 'Uploaded'
-- // more joins if necessary
WHERE T1.flag = 'Volunteer'

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries.  I'm not sure if you want other rows, but something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.code = 1) and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.code = 3) ;
```

If you just want the `col1`/`col2` pairs where this is true:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where code in (1, 3)
group by col1, col2
having count(distinct code) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, if I would like to have more columns included would that conflict with the HAVING Clause? or do I just need to include it in the GROUP BY. Can you explain the having .. = 2 part as well?

Comment: This actually helped steer me on the right path but was curious to know why it shows no results when you have more columns.

Comment: @PTurbo75 . . . I don't know.  This answers the question you have here.  If you have a different question with other columns, perhaps you should ask a new question.  The `= 2` is the number of values.  It says that both codes are in the group defined by `col1`/`col2`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.code = 1) and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.code = 3) ;

Comment: @Kamealon1234 . . . That checks if each of the codes exist for the col1/col2 combination.