# select with multiple condition on same column and Joining with other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to get a list of employees who have a particular set of certificates, e.g. BSCS and MSCS certificates.

**Certificates Table**

[image]

**Employee Certificates**

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u
JOIN employee_certificates e ON e.user_id = u.id
JOIN certificates c ON e.certificate_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 9 AND c.id=10
```

**Return Nothing**
But when I use

```
WHERE c.id IN (9,10)
```

**Returning employees** 206,207,208

Because they have these Certificates.

But what I want are the employees that have both BSCS and MSCS certificates.

Using this Query I can get result with Certificate id 9 and 10.. but how can i join user to get user detail.

```
Select certificate_id
from
(
Select distinct user_id, certificate_id
from
employee_certificates
where certificate_id in (9,10)
) a

group by certificate_id
```

i try this query but getting delicate result

```
 Select certificate_id,a.name
from
(
Select distinct user_id, certificate_id,u.name
from
employee_certificates
  JOIN users u ON u.id = employee_certificates.user_id
where certificate_id in (9,10)
) a
 
group by certificate_id,a.name
```

[image]

**What is Right Result i'm excepting?**
return only 1 user who's user_id is 206 has both certificate (9,10)

Comment: You asked [exactly the same question an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73269547/select-employee-who-has-multiple-certificate), and it was closed as a duplicate of a [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column).  The right action for you would be learn from the linked answers and apply them to your case, not to delete your question and repost it.

Comment: There where clause is a logical expression. `(x=9) AND (x=10)` can never evaluate to true. When you give it a row with a 9 you get `9=9 AND 9=10` which evaluates as `TRUE AND FALSE` which evaluates as `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
   SELECT u.*
     FROM employee_certificates ec
     JOIN users u ON u.id = ec.user_id
    WHERE ec.certificate_id IN (9, 10)
 GROUP BY ec.user_id
   HAVING COUNT(ec.user_id) = 2;
```

In case of same certificate allowed multiple times (thanks [matbailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie)):

```sql
   SELECT u.*
     FROM employee_certificates ec
     JOIN users u ON u.id = ec.user_id
    WHERE ec.certificate_id IN (9, 10)
 GROUP BY ec.user_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ec.certificate_id) = 2;
```

Adapt the HAVING condition to the number of certificates to check for.

Cheers

Comment: What if certificate more than 2 e.g 9,10,11,12,13 ?each time joining for same table is bad example

Comment: That‘s not what you asked in your question.

Comment: Please check 1st line again "Trying to get list of employee who has Both BSCS And MSCS certificate (may more certificate 3 or 5)."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: If a user can have multiple certificates with the same id, you'll need `COUNT(DISTINCT certificate_id)`

Comment: Yes, agree. I just tested it to be able to confirm it reliably.