# Inner Join with multiple search parameters unexpectedly returning empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Car

| ID | name | ModelNo | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VW Golf | 1121 | 2010 |
| 2 | Dodge | 3234 | 2016 |
| 3 | Audi | 5335 | 2394 |
| 4 | BMW | 6567 | 9090 |
| 5 | Toyota | 1221 | 9090 |

CarFeature

| ID | Feature |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ForkThickness |
| 2 | OperatorProtection |
| 3 | RearTires |

CarSpec

| ID | CarId | Value | CarFeatureId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.50 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Open Overhead | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | Summer Tires | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1.30 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | Closed Overhead | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | Winter Tires | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | 1.20 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | Closed Overhead | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | Winter Tires | 3 |

This returns `carId` and car name for cars where `Feature.Feature = 'ForkThickness'` and the corresponding `CarSpec.Value > 1.25` -- cars 1 and 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.Id, ca.Name 
FROM Car AS ca
INNER JOIN CarSpec AS cs ON ca.id = cs.CarId    
INNER JOIN CarFeature AS cf ON cf.Id = cs.CarFeatureId    
WHERE cf.Feature = 'ForkThickness' 
  AND cs.Value > 1.25
```

Including more features in the search parameters should return just car 1, but it's returning empty:

```
WHERE 
    Feature.Feature = 'ForkThickness' 
    AND CarSpec.Value > 1.25
    AND Feature.Feature = 'RearTires' 
    AND CarSpec.Value = 'Summer Tires'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is table Feature?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: `Feature.Feature = 'ForkThickness' [...] AND Feature.Feature = 'RearTires'` can never be true. Do you understand that the `where` keeps every row that meets its condition? We are saying, keep a row where X AND Y; we are are not saying, keep a row where X AND keep a row where Y. Maybe you want an OR not an AND. But since you don't say how output is a function of input, how would we know? Giving code that doesn't do what you want doesn't communicate what you wished it would do.

Comment: Clearly your error(s) & goal will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY ... HAVING` and conditional aggregation to assert multiple conditions. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4Jy7kVEi)

```
WITH CarsMatchingAllPredicates
     AS (SELECT cs.CarId
         FROM   CarSpec AS cs
                INNER JOIN CarFeature AS cf
                        ON cf.Id = cs.CarFeatureId
         GROUP  BY cs.CarId
         HAVING 0 NOT IN( MAX(IIF(( cf.Feature = 'ForkThickness' AND TRY_CAST(cs.Value AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) > 1.25 ), 1, 0)), 
                          MAX(IIF(( cf.Feature = 'RearTires' AND cs.Value = 'Summer Tires' ), 1, 0)) )
                        )
SELECT ca.Id,
       ca.Name
FROM   Car AS ca
WHERE  ca.Id IN (SELECT CarId
                 FROM   CarsMatchingAllPredicates)
```

Comment: That is slick! Could also use it with variables in a function/sproc.
MAX(IIF((\@DecimalFeature is null OR (cf.Feature = \@DecimalFeature AND TRY_CAST(cs.Value AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) > \@DecimalValue)), 1, 0)) AND 1 = MAX(IIF((\@StringFeature is null OR ( cf.Feature = \@StringFeature AND cs.Value = \@StringValue )), 1, 0))) -- could easily add more as needed with little effort.

Comment: Or `HAVING MAX(...) + MAX(...) = 2`

Comment: @Charlieface - I prefer the `0 NOT IN` as no need to adjust anything if a third condition is added (though adding could be useful if requirement was something like "at least 2" rather than "all")

Comment: If a dynamic number of conditions is required then I'd anyway recommend a different option such as using a TVP for all conditions, then using standard relational division such as `= (SELECT COUNT(*)` to check all conditions matched

Comment: Hi Martin thanks for taking the time to write all that out. I had a play with it and it is working great. I have a Q. There will be multiple more tables thaat will be linked through CarId and needing added to the inners. For exmaple Price table. So would the best approach be to continue adding to the inners...eg. (hope you dont mind I have edited your Q to explain this better) I included the inner join for price, and the Max IF for pr.currency and pr.Value...I tested this it works, my Q is can I keep building the query like this with more inner joins on other tables?

Comment: Also side note please...when adding price I am ref the inner as price.CarId against carSpec.CarId.....is this ok to continue doing this? So for example another table would be images...use Image.CarId and map to carSpec.CarId...my Q is this approach OK? maybe its my lack of knowledge I thought all mapping had to be done to the main PK holder so it all these tables would need inner join to Car.Id...not CarSpec.CarId....although this is working...is this best practice for performance is what I am asking? Again thankyou for the help thus far

Comment: @DaleK Ahh ok sorry about that... Should I undo that and ask another Q?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your attempt is that you are adding further join conditions, so you are looking for a single spec/feature with both conditions. Whereas actually you want to check for each condition separately. There are many ways to do this, but `EXISTS` is my choice, because it logically represents what you are trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT ca.Id, ca.Name 
FROM Car c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CarSpec cs
    JOIN CarFeature cf on cf.Id = cs.CarFeatureid
    WHERE cs.CarId = c.Id
    AND cf.Feature = 'ForkThickness' AND cs.Value > 1.25
);
```

And

```
SELECT ca.Id, ca.Name 
FROM Car c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CarSpec cs
    JOIN CarFeature cf on cf.Id = cs.CarFeatureid
    WHERE cs.CarId = c.Id
    AND cf.Feature = 'ForkThickness' AND cs.Value > 1.25
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CarSpec cs
    JOIN CarFeature cf on cf.Id = cs.CarFeatureid
    WHERE cs.CarId = c.Id
    AND cf.Feature = 'RearTires' AND cs.Value = 'Summer Tires'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried what you suggested and it is working as desired but my the data supplied was dummy data there will be alot more comparisons made with eg. (AND cf.Feature = 'exmaple1' AND cs.Value = 'exmaple1' )AND (cf.Feature = 'exmaple2' AND cs.Value = 'exmaple2') AND (cf.Feature = 'exmaple3' AND cs.Value = 'exmaple3') etcc  ....is it necessary to create an ADD EXISTS with the same first 4 lines for each exist? or can we refactor this somehow with minimum code? thank you again

Answer (score -1):

You code is looking for something that has both Feature.Feature = ForkThickness **AND** Feature.Feature = RearTires.

```
WHERE Feature.Feature = 'ForkThickness' AND CarSpec.Value > 1.25
AND Feature.Feature = 'RearTires' AND CarSpec.Value = 'Summer Tires'
```

This could be used with an OR statement instead to find options, otherwise you can remove the double "Feature.Feature" parameter/requirement.

Instead, replace the AND statement with an OR statement:

```
WHERE (Feature.Feature = 'ForkThickness' AND CarSpec.Value > 1.25)
OR (Feature.Feature = 'RearTires' AND CarSpec.Value = 'Summer Tires')
```

This would result in 2 cars being found.

Alternatively, if you are looking to get 1 result, you could use the following.
But just **check your logic** depending on what you actually require.

```
WHERE (Feature.Feature = 'ForkThickness' OR Feature.Feature = 
'RearTires') AND CarSpec.Value > 1.25 AND CarSpec.Value = 'Summer Tires'
```

Comment: Actually that doesn't work, because all your tests are carried out on a single row, whereas OP needs to test multiple rows as the other answers show.

Comment: Yes sorry, you're correct. I found this link to a similar post which can hopefully help OP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column